# Cannot view New Centos VPS in browser

Tags: php, apache, centos, lamp, vps

I have just registered for an unmanaged Centos 6 VPS. Have been following a guide to get lamp stack running, have followed instructions but when I try to view IP in browser I just get search results.

The steps I followed are:

- Fresh Centos 6 VPS configured by host
- Changed root pass
- yum install httpd (install apache)
- yum install php php-mysql (install php, sql)
- yum install php-common php-cli php-devel php-fpm php-gd php-imap php-intl php-mysql php-process php-xml php-xmlrpc php-zts (install common modules)
- Added ServerName localhost to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
- chkconfig httpd on (to run apache on startup)

The tutorial I am following states that I should be able to paste my IP into the browser and see a "Apache 2 Powered by Centos" demo page

Can anyone spot a problem with the current config?

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 Blocked by firewall:

/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables save